# LiqPay обрывает сессию. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Проблема вот в чем. Я делаю успешно оплату по этому сервису у себя на сайте где после оплаты автоматический редирект на метод в котором в таблице я обновляю статус об оплате и прочии нюансы.

Вот так я достаю имейл пользователя(он залогинен в этот момент)

```
string userEmail = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Но там null после редиректа. Что самое интересное, если я просто выберу в браузере зайти в этот метод, то там не будет null, даже если не буду обрывать дебаг, сначала после оплаты он обработает исключение и уведет на другую страницу и если я снова попробую перейти вручную в этот метод то там будет юзер. Я пытался заходить в этот метод через другой метод. Промежуточный. Ну типа я на сайт вернулся и от туда автоматом пересылаю на снова метод редирект. Работает, но тогда теряется почему-то ответ от сервера

```
var request_dictionary = Request.Form.Keys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => Request.Form[key]);
```

Который хранит в себе успех или нет об оплате. Замкнутый круг. Почему LiqPay обрывает сессию и как быть?

Comment: Возьмите отладчик http и проверьте, какие куки уходят в запросе к вашему сайту до и после редиректа. Посмотрите, теряются ли они.

Comment: Я пошел простым путем..и тут какие то демоны в студии. Я в промежуточном методе принимаю ответ от сервера и хочу его просто передать дальше в метод и делаю это через простой return RedirectToAction("RedirectEnd", "Account", new {_req = req}); Но в принимающем методе всегда null, как так, я весь инет перерыл и всеми вариантами пробывал, он не передает параметр.

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения. Который можно будет скопировать, вызвать - и получить потерю куки на редиректе

Comment: Пролему эту решил только через промежуточный метод, в котором записываю в переменные ответы ключей и передаю дальше в метод подтверждения об оплате уже на моей базе данных. Там уже  данные сеиси появляются